# Keep ratio of a div after resize, with overflow image-content in it

Tags: html, css

On my website, when you click on one of my projects, a lightbox opens, with in the middle, a container div containing two divs. One is on top with several pictures of the project in it, and underneath, a text in a white div, reaching the bottom of the page even if it's not full.

HTML organisation:

```
<div id="project_container">
    <div id="project_large12" class="project_large">
        <p> pictures with vertical scrolling</p>
    </div>
    <div id="project_text">
        <p class="project_description12"> Project description text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(in the real code, there are several 'project_largeXX' divs and 'project_descriptionXX' divs that I respectively hide with JS code.)

And the bit of CSS dealing with it :

```
#project_container
{
    position : fixed;
    top : 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width : 57.45%;
    height : 64.5%;
    background-color : #FFF000
}

.project_large
{
    position : absolute;
    width: 100%;
    line-height : 1.2;
    overflow : auto;
    height : 616px;
}

#project_text
{
    position : fixed;
    width: calc(57.2% - 40px);
    padding : 20px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align : justify;
    margin-top : 33%;           
    background-color : whitesmoke;
}

#project_text p
{
    margin : auto;
    font-family : 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size : 1.2em;
    text-align : justify;
    bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

What I need to do, is just manage to keep the ratio of the div containing the images in overflow whatever the width or height of the window is.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mh25w4r2/2/) is the piece of my code running the thing.

What I'm desperately trying to do is get that yellow div to keep a defined ratio -> the one of the first picture, or close to it, letting a bit of the second picture to appear. If you change the 'result' window's width or height on JSfiddle you can see that the yellow div will only connect the top of the project description div in some cases. With the overflow of the pictures, resizing it or even having a different resolution makes the image div grow underneath the project description div, and thus, screws up the scolling...

My website if you want to check : www.vincentleroux.fr

I'm reaching one more time the limits of my basic knowledge in coding. I know my code is dirty, well let's say filthy, so maybe there's a solution in which way I arrange my divs in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm desperately trying to do is get that yellow div to keep a defined ratio -> the one of the first picture, or close to it, letting a bit of the second picture to appear.

If I'm understanding this correctly, you should be able to accomplish this by setting a min height/width:

```
    min-width: XXpx;
    min-height: XXpx;
```

With this, the div won't go smaller than the min-size you set, regardless of how small the window gets. If the window gets too small for the div, it will add scroll bars.

You may want to set the min-height/width on the `container` element, as this should let both divs scale accordingly. If you only want the yellow div to keep this scale, just add these properties under that class.

Hope this helps!